# Can I say: You are out of my mind

Tags: sentence-meaning

If I don't care about my husband whatever he does or whatever he says, can I say to him "You are out of my mind"?

I got a hint from "out of sight, out of mind", but something strange is that 'out of one's mind' means 'insane'.

Is that correct?

Comment: "*You* are out of *your* mind" = "You are insane".  "*You* are out of *my* mind" is not a stable idiom.  I think it's easier to say, "I am not thinking of you at all".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not thinking of you, or I'm ignoring you, would be more appropriate choices. 
You are out of my mind is really not a phrase that is used.

Answer (score 0):

> You are out of **your** mind.

would be OK, though this is more likely used related to specific situations, and to describe disbelief at what someone said or did, not that you "don't care".

> You went out drinking until 1AM. *Are you out of your mind*?